# retURL on Button returns to correct record but is displayed as iframed version Salesforce within Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, urlhacking

I created a button on the Task Object that launches a flow to create a Quote record. I set the button to content source URL and entered the following:

```
https://{instance domain}/flow/{name of flow}?varContact={!Task.Who}
               &varTaskID={!Task.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Task.What}
```

I also tried

```
https://{instance domain}/flow/{name of flow}?varContact={!Task.Who}
               &varTaskID={!Task.Id}&retURL=/{!Task.What}
```

at completion of the flow, the page directs to the correct record but it is loading as an iframe of the salesforce page within the salesforce instance itself, which is not the expected behavior.

I was able to solve the issue and get it to just direct to the record using VF and a standardController with finishLocation. However, does anyone have any insight as to why I was experiencing the issue described above?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you are redirecting after completion of flow?

Comment: Right now the flow ends by creating a record. Then the VF page has a finishLocation with a retURL of WhatId (which is an opportunity) on the task.

Comment: I found some information here [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_url_set_retURL.htm) but it doesn't really explain situations when this happens nor how to mitigate it.

Comment: There is no merge field `{!Task.What}` - should be `{!Task.WhatId}`

Comment: @cropredy reviewing the formula for Button URL the merge field is {!Task.What} and {!Task.Who} if you look at these they are the actual field name of Name and Related To. The API Name for these are WhatId and WhoId which I would need to use on a VF page but doesn't seem to be the case in constructing these formulas.